# Enable Custom Draw Style in Sparx by Python

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

I am using python and Enterprise Architect (Sparx) API.
For some diagram objects in the diagram I want to set "Enable Custom Draw Style" (like below):

[image]

This information, whether "Enable Custom Draw Style" is selected or not, is stored in StyleEX of the diagram (not diagramObject). This has `"OPTIONS_(8 numbers of DUID)=CDS=1:;"`.
The idea is to get InstanceGUID of the diagram objects I want to hide, and then "paste" this DUID to existing StyleEx of diagram. And it works good when I can get DUID (InstanceGUID) of the diagram object.

However, sometime this DUID (InstanceGUID) is null. And also StyleEx of diagram is null. So I have no idea how to set this "Enable Custom Draw Style".

```
diag = EARepo.GetDiagramByGUID("{diagram_GUID}")

for diagObj in diag.DiagramObjects:
    print(diagObj.InstanceGUID)

>>> only empty strings
print(diag.StyleEx)
>>> also empty string

EARepo.SaveDiagram(diag.DiagramID)
diag.Update()
for diagObj in diag.DiagramObjects:
    diagObj.Update()
diag.DiagramObjects.Refresh()
diag.Update()

EARepo.SaveDiagram(diag.DiagramID)
```

here also after all those "tries" I get empty InstanceGUID of diagObj, nor StyleEx of diagram. In the SQLQuery there is no InstanceGUID nor DUID, only InstanceID (but this will not help here).

When I go to diagram directly in Enterprise Architect, change anything and save diagram - it indeed creates InstanceGUID. However, nothing works so far when I try to do this via script...

Is there any way to "force" EA to add those InstanceGUIDs to diagram objects?
Or different way to select this: "Enable Custom Draw Style"

Comment: The use of these DUIDs is weird - EA typical. It can well be that they do not generate them with the API but only via the GUI :-( You could send a bug report, but you must not hold your breath.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that the cases where the InstanceGUID is null, is when the DiagramObject is still new.

So in order to make sure you have the latest greatest you can get them again from the repository.

```
diagram = Repository.GetDiagramByID(diagram.DiagramID);
foreach (var diagramObject in diagram.DiagramObjects)
{
  //add DUID to diagram.StyleEx
}
```

If it then still doesn't work, you can get the info directly from the database

```
var result = Repository.SQLQuery($"select * from t_diagramObjects do where do.ElementID = {element.ElementID} and do.DiagramID = {diagram.DiagramID}");
```

And then load the result into an XML object and get the info you need.

The DUID is stored in the column `ObjectStyle` as a key/value pair:

```
DUID=005B353D;
```

Comment: I would guess that Geert is right with hist first assumption. Try to do a SaveDiagram before looking into the InstanceGUID..

Answer (score 0):

Often there is a back door (espcially in the EA house). It looks like you can simply create your own DUID when EA does not. I ran a quick test where I replaced the EA-created DUID with my own and EA got no hickups. I made diagram with a single element having the custom draw style set. It's DUID was EC1540D2. I'm using my own Python framework but for the gist it's self-explanatory enough.

```
dia = rep.getDiagramByGUID("{48406942-D5E5-4146-A8B8-2F9D5A4156E8}")
s = dia.styleEx.replace("OPTIONS_EC1540D2", "OPTIONS_12345678")
dia.styleex = s
dia.update
for do in dia.diagramObjects:
    rep.execute("UPDATE t_diagramobjects SET objectStyle='DUID=12345678;' WHERE Object_ID=%d" % do.elementid)
```

So I first alter the stored DUID in the diagram. Then I overwrite the ObjectStyle with my DUID 12345678. And EA still shows the custom style.

So what you can do is to use a GUID generator (`import uuid`) and create your own DUIDs for your diagram objects. You need to inject them with SQL since ObjectStyle in the API is r/o. The StyleEx in the diagram however can be set via the API.